# Understanding a precursor to the complex Taylor Series

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

First $f_n(z)$ is defined as

$$
f_n(z) = {f_{n-1(z) - f_{n-1}(a)} \over z - a}
$$

for all $1, \ldots , n$.and s.t. $f_n(a) = f_{n-1}'(a)$.  From this it is derived that

$$
f(z) = f(a) + (z-a)f_1(z)
$$
$$
f_1(z) = f_1(a) + (z-a)f_2(z)
$$
$$
\vdots
$$
$$
f_{n-1}(z) = f_{n-1}(a) + (z-a)f_n(z)
$$

so that evidently we have

$$
f(z) = f(a) + (z-a)f_1(a) + \underbrace{(z-a)^2f_2(a) + \ldots + (z-a)^{n-1}f_{n-1}(a)+(z-a)^n f_n(z)}_{\text{so that this must be $0$}}
$$

**Question:** How exactly is this last equation being derived from the above ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Induction: Suppose that
$$f(z) = f(a) + (z-a)f_1(a) + (z-a)^2f_2(a) + \ldots + (z-a)^{n-2}f_{n-2}(a)+(z-a)^{n-1} f_{n-1}(z).$$
Then since 
$$(z-a)^{n-1}f_{n-1}(z) = (z-a)^{n-1}f_{n-1}(a) + (z-a)^nf_n(z),$$
you get your expression.